# Using OpenShift with many components

Tags: scalability, openshift-origin

I am in the process of evaluating using OpenShift Origin (or maybe enterprise) for a project with many components, but I am having some problems figuring out what the best solution to split up the components and keep scalability.

The components are

- db (PostgreSQL): Used a lot, but not that much for writing, so I can scale it using 1 write and several reads.
- www (static files): Served by nginx or similar
- api (django): That the www app can talk to. Need to talk to the db, and cache.
- auth (NodeJS): Authentication frontend for social authentication, need contact with the cache.
- sse (django): DataPush using html5, this webserver haveto be running nginx/gevent or similar. This need to talk to MQ.
- MQ (RabbitMQ): For running tasks.
- cache (redis): That the api, sse and auth talks to..

Overall complicated, but it all works great right now without OpenShift.

Looking at how people are running Django and Postgres in Openshift, its normally done using (from another example) something like `rhc app create --scaling $APP_NAME python-2.7 mongodb-2.4 postgresql-8.4`, but what does this really do? As I understand, you will end up with python, mongodb, and postgres running on the same machine in this case.

What is the the best solution in this case?

- Running the whole stack on 1 app. So that technically it will be running the everything per physical server.
- Creating 1 scalable application for the major components, and example point the api db setting to db-mydom.example.com?
- Only using OpenShift for www and api, and setting up old style servers on the rest?
- Something completly different?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an application and enable scaling, in your above scenario, you would end up with mongo on it's own gear, postgresql on it's own gear, and then a gear for your haproxy/web application.  As you get more requests to your application, it would automatically add more web gears and direct traffic to them from the haproxy.

Comment: Thanks.. That explained some of my confusion. But what will happen if I put my other app, with web, redis, postgres, nodejs, mq all in one app. Will I end up with only the web gear scaling and all the others being on a single gear? Or isn't OpenShift ready for this kind of apps yet, and I should not use it for everything, just some of the components..?